# Chess game where first person puts down a knight and then they move the knight, whoever can't make a move loses

Tags: invariance, chessboard

The knight is the only piece on the board, and it cannot visit a space more than once. I have barely any ideas. However, I know that a knight changes the color it is on every move, but I can't put that fact into use.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? Are there other pieces on the board? Does it have to change colors or is that just a thought? etc

Comment: There are no other pieces. The first player puts down a knight on any square, and then the second player takes turns to move the knight. The knight cannot go to a square that was already visited. Whoever cannot make a valid move loses

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that, it is an important piece of information.

Comment: I don't see a question here.  The body of the Question should contain a full problem statement.